# How would I go about adding a python code runner to my website

Tags: javascript, python, html

Alright, so basically, I own this website: https://quarkedit.ga which right now has a HTML/CSS/JS editor using Ace. Now what I need is I also have a python language one, but I don't know how to make the terminal or whatever show up. I'm going for something like https://repl.it 's python thing. Just wondering if there is any API which i could use, something like

```
output = evaluatePythonCode("print(\"test\")");
```

I basically want to know and find out these things:

- What API's can I use to do this?
- What would the syntax be?
- Can I do this with pure HTML/CSS/JS or would I have to use a JS
  Library?

I have the input for the code done, and the syntax highlighting (Ace) But what I need is the:

- Execution
- Output

  All help will be appreciated, and if this question isn't appropriate or anything just comment and I'll remove it.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing this question will be considered too broad to reasonably answer in this format. I'd suggest breaking this down into smaller problems and letting us know if you have more specific questions. For example, there's the text entry part, the syntax highlighting, the execution, and displaying of the REPL results, for some.

Comment: @Jacob Is that better? Thanks for the suggestion, before immediately down voting :)

Comment: Much better now that you've narrowed the problem, thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `repl.it` and most similar sites just pipe things to their server to be executed, which is not what you want here.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah you're right, but I looked at the website mentioned in the answer http://pypyjs.org/ seems like a good choice

Comment: The _ideal_ solution here is probably to run either CPython or PyPy via emscripten's 2.x or successor project that builds wasm instead of asm.js … except for the fact that you're at least a few months early for that. The various emscripten 1.x Python projects, like PyPy.js, are halfway decent today, and probably the closest thing to what the future will be, but in some ways PyBee, Brython, Skulpt, Jaspy, etc. might be better today, especially since they may be getting more use today. So you should really take at least a brief look at all the options before deciidng.

Comment: @abarnert Good Idea, thanks that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options: either evaluate the Python in the browser or post it back to some server that can spawn a Python process to evaluate the code.

For the former, [there are a few Python-implemented-via-JavaScript solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+implemented+in+JavaScript&oq=python+implemented+in+JavaScript&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.3439j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) out there, which I can't personally vouch for but would be the faster option and wouldn't require you to have servers to execute the code. [PyPy.js](http://pypyjs.org/) has a REPL in a browser available to play with, so that's worth taking a look at.

For server-side execution, there's a ton of approaches, all depending on your server technologies, which Python interpreter you're using, how you're going to handle security/DOS, etc.

Hopefully that helps you get started.

Comment: Thanks! I think PyPy.js seems easier for me, I don't want to have to deal with server-side execution :)

Answer (score 1):

First create a file.py to write code to and execute.

You can use javascript to send a `XMLHttpRequest` to a python file

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "exec?text=" + code, true);
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var output = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    // do something with the output
}
xhr.send();
```

And using Flask and subprocess in the python file:

```
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/exec', methods=['POST']) // route app to /exec
def result():
    with open('file.py', 'w') as code: // 'w' means to override existing code in the file
        code.write(request['code']) // write the code
    return subprocess.check_output(["python", "file.py"]) // execute the code using the terminal
```

Return the output of the code. Please tell me if this does not work. Thanks!